# Returning an Oracle error in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql

Not sure if that makes sense, but say I have this code...

```
$updateSql = oci_parse($conn, 'update "table" SET
"column"=:column where "Unique_Record_Id" = :Unique_Record_Id');
OCIBindByName($updateSql, ":Unique_Record_Id", $absenceData['Unique_Record_Id']);
OCIBindByName($updateSql, ":column", $column);

if(oci_execute($updateSql)){
 // np
} else {
 echo "I want an error code here please :(";
}
```

Is there anyway to display an ORA error message in the else statement please? Apologies for the random question, but since binding doesn't really generate proper SQL I can't just copy & paste it easily into SQL developer.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the specific ORA error, and why the double quotes?

Comment: Not sure on the ORA error unfortunately - that's what I was trying to get at! :-)

Not sure why I use the double quotes... I find sometimes it won't work without them, so put them in just in case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would use [`oci_error($updateSql)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) in your `else` block to retrieve the error code and message from Oracle.

Comment: So simple, but works absolutely perfectly! Returns the ORA code, description and the SQL - absolutely perfect, thanks!!